# In build.sbt, dependencies in parent project not reflected in child modules

Tags: scala, apache-spark, module, sbt

I am using SBT 1.8.0 for my spark scala project in intellij idea 2017.1.6 ide. I want to create a parent project and also its children project modules. So far this is what I have in my build.sbt:

```
lazy val parent = Project("spark-etl-parent",file("."))
.settings(
name := "spark-etl-parent_1.0",
scalaVersion := "2.11.1",
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided" 
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion % "provided")
)

lazy val etl = Project("spark-etl-etl",file("etl"))
.dependsOn(parent)
.settings(
name := "spark-etl-etl_1.0",
version := "1.0",
scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
)

lazy val redshiftBasin = Project("spark-etl- 
redshiftBasin",file("redshiftBasin"))
.dependsOn(parent)
.settings(
name := "spark-etl-redshiftBasin_1.0",
version := "1.0",
scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
 )


lazy val s3Basin = Project("spark-etl-s3Basin",file("s3Basin"))
.dependsOn(parent)
.settings(
name := "spark-etl-s3Basin_1.0",
version := "1.0",
scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
)
```

Now I am able to import any  class from spark-streaming or spark-hive library dependencies in the parent module but not able to import and use them in any of the child modules. Only if I explicitly specify them as a library dependency in the any child module, I am able to use them.

1. I am looking for something similar to dependencies tag in pom.xml with Maven build.
2. Will it make a difference if I use separate build.sbt for each of the child modules?
3. Also if I do .aggregate(etl) in parent config, it shows error as etl is declared later. But if I define etl before parent I am not able to do .dependsOn(parent) in etl config.

Please help me with a solution to fix these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My multi-module project uses the parent project only for building everything and delegate run to the 'server' project:

```
lazy val petstoreRoot = project.in(file(".")).
  aggregate(sharedJvm, sharedJs, server, client)
  .settings(organizationSettings)
  .settings(
    publish := {}
    , publishLocal := {}
    , publishArtifact := false
    , isSnapshot := true
    , run := {
      (run in server in Compile).evaluated
    }
  )
```

The settings (e.g. dependencies) I grouped in another file, e.g.:

```
  lazy val sharedDependencies: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Def.settings(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.julienrf" %%% "play-json-derived-codecs" % "4.0.0"
   ...
    , "org.scalatest" %%% "scalatest" % scalaTestV % Test

  ))
```

Now each sub-module just adds whatever is needed, e.g.:

```
lazy val server = (project in file("server"))
  .settings(scalaJSProjects := Seq(client))
  .settings(sharedSettings(Some("server"))) // shared dependencies used by all
  .settings(serverSettings)
  .settings(serverDependencies)
  .settings(jvmSettings)
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala, BuildInfoPlugin)
  .dependsOn(sharedJvm)
```

The whole project you find here: https://github.com/pme123/scala-adapters

See the `project/Settings` file for the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to make changes only in the build.sbt. I have now found out that the problem, is with scope I've given: "provided", seems it doesn't support transitive dependency and only if we give scope as "compile", the dependencies are propagated to the children. i am still wondering if it's possible to propagate the dependencies from parent to children even if the scope is "provided".

Comment: @SatishSrinivas my solution works also in `build.sbt` only. As `build.sbt` is just an enhanced `Scala class`

Comment: Thanks,  but I did a similar thing in my build.sbt, but when I give .aggregate (sub-projects) in the parent project definition, it says not able to resolve : recursive value sub-project needs type.  Is it because the sub-projects are defined after the parent or due to sbt version problem?

Comment: I never had this problem. according to the message you can set a type for the sub-projects, like: `lazy val server: Project = (project in file("server")).....`

Comment: thanks for your help. I have figured out a way to execute the tasks separately. But I think it affects when we build jars separately for the sub-projects. When I do package command for sub-project, it only gives jar with classes from child, but not from parent classes it is dependent on. Is building a fat jar with assembly the only way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `provided->provided` in the `dependsOn` helped me solve a similar problem:

So something like:

```
lazy val etl = Project("spark-etl-etl",file("etl"))
.dependsOn(parent % "compile->compile;test->test;provided->provided")
.settings(
name := "spark-etl-etl_1.0",
version := "1.0",
scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
)
```