# sbt publishLocal of a project with provided dependencies in build.sbt doesn't make these dependencies visible to projects using the project as library

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

Let's suppose I have a project 'internal-library' with this build.sbt:

```
organization := "com.foo"
name := "internal-library"
version := "1.0.0"
scalaVersion := "2.13.13"

...other stuff...

libraryDependencies += "com.mysql" % "mysql-connector-j" % "8.0.32"
libraryDependencies += "com.clickhouse" % "clickhouse-jdbc" % "0.4.6"

...other dependencies...

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.5.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.5.1" % "provided"
)
```

The project 'internal-library' contains code and dependencies that are useful for many other projects and it's published in local repository with command `sbt clean publishLocal`.

Now, let's suppose I have a project 'abc' with this build.sbt:

```
organization := "com.foo"
name := "abc"
version := "1.0.0"
scalaVersion := "2.13.13"

...other stuff...

libraryDependencies += "com.foo" %% "internal-project" % "1.0.0"
```

All the dependencies declared in build.sbt of 'internal-project' are also visible and usable for compilation to project 'abc' except the ones declared as provided.

At this point I'm forced to add also in the sub project the spark library dependencies, but I would like to have them declared in only one place and they should be declared as provided because spark cluster already owns spark's jars and it doesn't need them in the fat jar of project 'abc'.

Comment: That's the point of `Provided` scope. Though I think with Maven you could have these provided deps in a Maven parent, I don't think there's an easy way to do the same with SBT. You could create a SBT plugin to share the list of deps across all your projects. Or maybe you can use sbt-bom if Spark provides a BOM to simplify things a bit.

Comment: I agree with you that provided scope has this meaning but I think that the behaviour is still a bit strange: if I check .ivy2/local/internal-library_2.13 both ivy.xml and internal-library_2.13.pom have the lines regarding spark deps. At this point the child project (abc) should know about those import, even if with provided scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution.
The build.sbt of the child ('abc' project) should be:

```
organization := "com.foo"
name := "abc"
version := "1.0.0"
scalaVersion := "2.13.13"

...other stuff...

libraryDependencies += "com.foo" %% "internal-project" % "1.0.0" % "compile->compile;provided->provided"
```

In this way you can avoid to include provided dependencies already declared in parent project ('internal-library').

I've got inspiration for this solution by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67414067/6593151) on stack overflow and by sbt [documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html#Classpath+dependencies).

Comment: Nice, didn't know about this feature.